# SQL Server is not releasing memory after Daily Load

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, 128GB of RAM, Windows 2008R2. The SQL Server job runs every day at 3 AM and takes 5 hrs to load data into the database. During this process, SQL Server utilizes 123GB (max memory allocated).

After the job completes, SQL Server is not releasing the RAM.

Queried memory utilization where buffer pool shows 97GB. Users don't access database during this time. I restarted SQL Server services to bring RAM down. I didn't find a correct answer related to this issue. Why is it not releasing the RAM? How can we bring RAM utilization down?

SQL Server Job -> SSIS package -> Import data from Mysql to SQL Server database

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem this causes?

Comment: Once grabbed, SQL server will NOT release memory resources. The assumption is that SQL is the most important application running on the server. You should research possible solutions in the [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thank You for responding . I understood SQL server will not release memory resources.But won't it release if nothing is running on the sever? I research in DBA site couldn't find correct answer :( @NotAnAuthor

Comment: "How can we bring RAM utilization down?" You must first ask yourself *why* you want to bring RAM utilization down. You didn't buy those 128 GB to sit idle, right? And the server *is* dedicated to SQL Server, right? So SQL Server grabbing all the memory and using it as a big cache is actually things working by design. If the server is *not* fully dedicated to SQL Server, but supposed to run other processes that are memory intensive (like SSIS or SSAS) it's another matter, and then configuring `max server memory` makes sense, but otherwise reducing memory use isn't actually going to help.

Comment: If the server runs other software, work out how much memory that software needs and limit SQL Server so that much is reserved. Probably you are OK limiting SQL to 124GB reserving 4GB to "everything else".

Comment: Not helpful, Jeroen, people have more use cases than the one you're familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design once SQL Server uses memory, it keeps hold of it and does not release it back to OS.

Your Task Manager may show all/nearly all memory used by SQL Server but if you want to see how much memory SQL Server is actually using you can use the following query.

```
SELECT    (physical_memory_in_use_kb/1024) AS Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB
FROM sys.dm_os_process_memory;
```

Comment: It's showing  120GB is using SQL server . Nothing is running on SQL server box but it still shows 120GB utilization. @M.Ali

Comment: @adityay Which column in `sys.dm_os_process_memory` is showing 120GB in use? Also do you have `sp_WhoIsActive` , if so run that and see what is running on the server?

Comment: Thank You for responding .Memory_usedby_Sqlserver_MB is showing 120GB. I ran sp_Whoisactive and nothing is running on the server. @M.Ali

Comment: How can you configure this behavior? The server is using ~1.5G while doing absolutely nothing on my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

By design, SQL Server holds on to the RAM that is has allocated.  Much of the RAM is used for the buffer pool.  The buffer pool is a cache that holds database pages in memory for fast retrieval.

If SQL Server were to release some memory, and someone were to run a query that requests it right afterwards, the query would have to wait for expensive physical I/O to produce the data.  Therefore, SQL Server tries to hold as much memory as possible (and as configured) for as long as possible.

The [RAM settings here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-2017) specify the *min server memory* and the *max server memory*.  Careful setting of the max memory setting allows room for other processes to run.  The article quotes a complicated formula for determining how much room to leave:

> - From the total OS memory, reserve 1GB-4GB to the OS itself.
> - Then subtract the equivalent of potential SQL Server memory allocations
>     outside the max server memory control, which is comprised of stack
>     size 1 * calculated max worker threads 2 + -g startup parameter 3 (or
>     256MB by default if -g is not set). What remains should be the
>     max_server_memory setting for a single instance setup.

In our servers, we usually just wing it and set the max memory option to several GB below the total physical memory.  This leaves plenty of room for the OS and other applications.

If SQL Server memory is over the *min server memory*, and the OS is under memory pressure, SQL Server can release memory until it is at the *min server memory* setting.

Reference: [Memory Management Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/memory-management-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-2017#includessnoversionincludesssnoversion-mdmd-memory-architecture).

> One of the primary design goals of all database software is to
>   minimize disk I/O because disk reads and writes are among the most
>   resource-intensive operations. SQL Server builds a buffer pool in
>   memory to hold pages read from the database. Much of the code in SQL
>   Server is dedicated to minimizing the number of physical reads and
>   writes between the disk and the buffer pool. SQL Server tries to reach
>   a balance between two goals:
>
> - Keep the buffer pool from becoming so big that the entire system is low on memory.
> - Minimize physical I/O to the database files by maximizing the size of the buffer pool.
>
> When SQL Server is using memory dynamically, it queries the system
>   periodically to determine the amount of free memory. Maintaining this
>   free memory prevents the operating system (OS) from paging. If less
>   memory is free, SQL Server releases memory to the OS. If more memory
>   is free, SQL Server may allocate more memory. SQL Server adds memory
>   only when its workload requires more memory; a server at rest does not
>   increase the size of its virtual address space.
>
> ...
>
> As more users connect and run queries, SQL Server acquires the
>   additional physical memory on demand. A SQL Server instance continues
>   to acquire physical memory until it either reaches its max server
>   memory allocation target or Windows indicates there is no longer an
>   excess of free memory; it frees memory when it has more than the min
>   server memory setting, and Windows indicates that there is a shortage
>   of free memory.
>
> As other applications are started on a computer running an instance of
>   SQL Server, they consume memory and the amount of free physical memory
>   drops below the SQL Server target. The instance of SQL Server adjusts
>   its memory consumption. If another application is stopped and more
>   memory becomes available, the instance of SQL Server increases the
>   size of its memory allocation. SQL Server can free and acquire several
>   megabytes of memory each second, allowing it to quickly adjust to
>   memory allocation changes.

If, for some reason:

1. You absolutely MUST have that memory back
2. You know you do not need it for a while
3. You are willing to pay a penalty for virtual memory allocation and physical I/O to retrieve data from disk the next time you need that memory

Then you can temporarily reconfigure the database *max server memory* setting to a lower value.  This can be done through the SSMS user interface, or you can use an `sp_configure 'max server memory'` followed by `reconfigure` to make the changes programatically.

Comment: It's been my experience that merely reconfiguring `max server memory` on a running instance may not be enough to make SQL Server relinquish the memory it's already claimed, at least not speedily. A follow-up `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` may be necessary. For obvious reasons, this should never be done on a production server that's in active use, as it discards the entire buffer cache and will force all subsequent queries to go through physical I/O... but if you need it, you need it. (Which should only be the case if the server was badly configured to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I did not try it myself. 
You should not try it on your production environment before testing it somewhere else.

This is from a [DBA answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194721/how-to-clean-up-memory-usage-of-a-database-after-a-big-sql-query):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

`4096` should be replaced by the value that you find acceptable as the minimum.

Should be followed by a similar command to increase the memory back to your original maximum.